Is there a way to mock prefers-reduced-motion in tests running using Jest?
I'm writing some tests using Jest and React-testing library. In my tests, I'd like to simulate the case in which users have reduced-motion set on their devices.
I tried the following, but it didn't work:
describe('TestComponent', () => {

it('should make selection with reduced motion preference', async () => {
    setReducedMotionPreference(true);
    render(<TestApp />);

    // open select component, which produces animation
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByText('option 2'));
    
    // choose another option from the select options
    const option1 = screen.getByTitle('option 1');
    await userEvent.click(option1);

    // verify that option 1 is selected and option 2 not
    expect(option1.classList.contains('ant-select-item-option-selected')).toBeTruthy();
    const option2 = screen.getByTitle('option 2');
    expect(option2.classList.contains('ant-select-item-option-selected')).toBeFalsy();
  });
});

Here's the implementation of setReducedMotionPreference:
const setReducedMotionPreference = value => {
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => {
    return {
      matches: query === '(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)' ? value : false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    };
  });
};

When I debug, I see that window.matchMedia('(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)').matches is true. On the browser (I've set reduced motion on my OS) the select (imported from ant-design UI library) component isn't working as expected, so I expect the test to fail, but it passes.
Am I doing something wrong in the mocking or this is simply not possible to test in JSDOM?
